# Sorry! the process com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again. force close

Tags: force-close

Why does this keep appearing on my phone which cuases my network to go off and on.

Comment: Can you please mention ROM using,Rooted/Non-rooted and also which device?

Answer (score 2):

### On samsung devices

Over on the Sprint forums, they've posted a fix for this without needing a reset: Go into *Menu -> Settings -> Call settings -> Reject with message.* If you have more than 5 messages in there, delete some so you have less than 5.

People are reporting that once they do that, they are once again able to receive calls without the force close happening. Hope that helps!

### In case its an HTC device follow this

1. Go to your facebook app and under *synchronize settings* choose to delete all facebook data. Afterwards log out of the facebook app.
2. Go to *account and synchronizing* settings and remove any facebook entries. Now your contacts should no longer contain any data from facebook and should not be linked with facebook either.
3. Go to the facebook app, sign in and re-choose the synchronizing settings. Press "synchronize" in upper right corner.
4. Go to *accounts and synchronizing* and add facebook for HTC Sense and perhaps also the normal facebook account. It will now start re-synchronizing everything and you have to link all your contacts again, but it now works

**If both methods didn't work for you go for an [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) that will surely solve your network and call issues.**

Answer (score -1):

This error message would not go away until I cleared my call log history.